# Computing a double integral over a surface S, where S is the unit sphere,

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry, surface-integrals

$$ \int \int_S (x^2+y^2)d\sigma$$

Where S is the unit sphere centered at (0,0,0), and $\sigma$ is surface area.

I arrived at the correct answer of $\large \frac{8\pi}{3}$, but I took an (educated?) guess on the set-up of the integral.

Instead of the usual volume element of the sphere, in spherical coordinates,

$$dV=\rho^2sin(\phi)d\rho d\theta d\phi$$

I just simply omitted the $\rho^2 d\rho$ factor of the Jacobian and guessed that the remaining factor $$sin(\phi) d\theta d\phi$$

represents the "surface area element" of the sphere.

Integration gave me the correct answer, and I didn't have to think about the tricky ndS factor to compute.

Is my work ok - or did I arrive at the correct answer with a wrong method?

Any suggestions or alternative solutions are welcome -- especially if you would like to comment on the computation of the n.dS factor in this problem.

EDIT:  I think I may have completely missed the point of the question, too.  My trying to get an n.dS factor is only relevant for *flux* *integrals* of *vector* *fields*.  This question is an "ordinary" double integral over the surface area of a sphere -- it is not considered a "surface integral".  Do I have it correct now?  So, what I really should be doing is to compute a Jacobian determinant factor.  But would the Jacobian be a determinant of a 2x2 matrix or 3x3?  I feel that if I compute it for a 3x3 matrix, then I am computing the Jacobian determinant for a *volume* integral, and not an surface area integral -- which is a bit confusing.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using spherical coordinates as follows $$y=r\sin\theta\cos\phi$$ $$x=r\sin\theta\sin\phi$$ 
$$d\sigma=\text{Elementary surface area of sphere}$$$$=(r\sin\theta d\phi)(rd\theta)=r^2\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$$

Now, $$\int\int_S(x^2+y^2)d\sigma$$
$$=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}(r^2\sin^2\theta\cos^2\phi+r^2\sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi)r^2\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$$
$$=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}(r^2\sin^2\theta(\cos^2\phi+\sin^2\phi))r^2\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$$

$$=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}r^4\sin^3\theta d\theta d\phi$$
$$=r^4\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^3\theta d\theta d\phi$$
Setting $r=\text{radius of unit sphere}=1$
$$=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left[\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{3\sin\theta-\sin 3\theta}{4}d\theta \right]d\phi$$
$$=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left[-\frac{3}{4}\cos\theta+\frac{1}{12}\cos 3\theta \right]_{0}^{\pi}d\phi$$
$$=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left[\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{6} \right]d\phi$$
$$=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left[\frac{4}{3}\right]d\phi$$
$$=\frac{4}{3}\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\phi$$
$$=\frac{4}{3}[\phi]_{0}^{2\pi}$$
$$=\frac{4}{3}[2\pi]=\frac{8\pi}{3}$$

Comment: Hi @HarishChandraRajpoot, I think I am getting tripped up in the wording of this problem and have realized my major mistake in thinking:  this is an "ordinary" double integral, and we can compute a Jacobian determinant factor and get a surface element.  I've been trying this whole time to make sense of trying to find n.dS, but I think n.dS is only for *flux* *integrals*, which are surface integrals.  Regarding this double integral, we do not even *have* a vector field to consider.  What do you think?  Thanks for your time,

Answer (score 2):

The correct surface element for spherical coordinates is given by $dS = \rho^2 \sin \phi \cdot d\theta d\phi$ (whose derivation is widely available, e.g. in textbooks), i.e. the surface element you used is missing a factor of $\rho^2$.

You were asked to integrate over the unit sphere, i.e. $\rho = 1$ everywhere, so in this case your omission of $\rho$ did not have an impact on your answer. (So in fact, the surface element you used is correct--you happened to correctly simplify the expression for $dS$ in this special case!)

If you were asked to integrate over some other shape, say a cylinder (for some reason...), with the coordinates you used, you would have gotten a wrong answer.

Comment: Hi @KenWei -- shouldn't I be trying to set up an n.dS factor?  I found my normal vector by taking a cross-product of two derivative vectors, one with respect to the variable $\theta$ and the other with respect to the variable $\phi$.  I then get a 3-tuple vector that is normal to the sphere.  I then normalized this vector.  Now my confusion is:  this vector is of course not equal to your *factor* of $\rho^2 sin(\phi)$.  How should I interpret this difference?   Thanks,

Comment: No, you are integrating a scalar function (unless you are talking about some interpretation of surface area from dot products that I'm not aware of); so n.dS is irrelevant in this case. You may be getting confused with an integral of a vector function, in which case you are looking at integrating (v.n)dS where v is the vector function.

Comment: Ok, got it -- thanks for your time, @KenWei :-)